# Destroy clones of Gameobject after collision in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have made a 2D game unity, and I have "RockSpawner" gameobject which spawns rocks when game starts. If my player collides with any this rocks, I want to destroy rock clones (Spawned by RockSpawner) or set all rock clones made in game play mode to false.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You need to show your attempt and make a specific problem statement ("I tried this: [code], but X doesn't happen the way I want"), see [How to write an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sure bro you are right, but how can I  put the code that i haven't sorted yet, I have no idea of how to do it, that's why I'm asking this Question?

Comment: There's a concept around here called "show what you tried." You haven't tried yet, so maybe you should try that.

Comment: Hope someone knows it or at least give me some direction !

Comment: I do have working game, But thing I want, to destroy gameobject clone ?

Comment: Oh, I could probably write some code to do it, but I'm not going to do it *for* you. At least, not for less than the current going rate of a freelance Unity developer. Which is $120 an hour (minimum 8 hours). Your question does not contain any code that you currently have that allows your game to be complete and working, except this one detail. I don't know what you do and do not have.

Comment: Thanks for try bro, please, leave it to someone else!

Comment: No one else is going to answer this question either. And for the same reasons. This is not what Stack Overflow is for. See [the help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0):

Basically , if you look on the internet there are a lot of examples.
However , the best way is to use :
[OnCollision2DEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html)

From the example in the link given there is :

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
            coll.gameObject.SendMessage("ApplyDamage", 10);

    }
}
```

From here you can then use "Destroy" .

Comment: I have found a way to do that and I used "DestroyGameobjectwithtag" which worked for me here! I have assigned a tag to Instantiated object and Destroyed clones when Collision with "Player" happened.